# url parameter button in custom object. - possible?

Tags: database, salesforce

I just have a custom object with a custom URL button. I would like the button to link to another custom object and pass a few fields over. When I make the parameter the ID of the textbox it works but only if I manually enter a value into the url. I need to get the value of a field automatically.

This doesn't work:

```
salesforce.com\customobject\?00Nd00000051jy4={!form_email_address}
```

If I use this link, the new page just populates the field with {!form_email_address} and not the passed value

Answer (score 0):

If **from_email_address** is a *custom field* in your custom object the link should be:

```
/CustomObjTargetId/e?CustomObjFieldTargetName={!From_email_address__c}
```

Don't forget the **__c** to indicate salesforce that is a custom field.